# Storing/retriving a Codable Dictionary of structs in UserDefaults doesn't work for me

Tags: xcode, nsuserdefaults, codable, swift5

Swift (v 5/5.1) newbie here, having a hard time with Codables...hoping to get some advise from the experts here.

Okay, I have a simple dictionary from struct where the key is a string. I want to store the dictionary in UserDefaults (and later retrieve). There are some quite similar questions here, but these are mainly addressing nested struct's.

First attempt (error handling removed for simplicity):

```
public struct PriceStruct:Codable {
    var myPrice: Double
    var myTime: TimeInterval
    var selected: Bool
    var direction: Int
    var myHigh, myLow: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case myPrice = "myPrice"
        case myTime = "myTime"
        case selected = "selected"
        case direction = "direction"
        case myHigh = "myHigh"
        case myLow = "myLow"
    }
}

var myPrices: [String: PriceStruct] = [:]

// [fill myPrices with some data...]

func savePrices() {
   // error: Attempt to set a non-property-list object
   UserDefaults.standard.set(myPrices, forKey: "prices")
}

func loadPrices() {
   // obviously this doesn't work either
   let myPrices = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "prices")
}
```

```
While I assumed from the documentation, that UserDefaults is capable of storing dictionaries, it doesn't - at least for me.
Next thing I tried was using JSONEncoder like this:

    // this time with prior JSON encoding
    func savePrices() {
       // this works
       let json = try! JSONEncoder().encode(myPrices)
       UserDefaults.standard.set(json as Data, forKey: "prices")
    }

    func loadPrices() {
       // this doesn't work
       let json = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "prices")
       let decoder = JSONDecoder()
       let decoded = try! decoder.decode(PriceStruct.self, from json!)
    }
```

Unfortunately I'm getting an error when trying to load data back from UserDefaults:
`Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "myPrice", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"myPrice\", intValue: nil) (\"myPrice\").", underlyingError: nil))`

Other variants I tried is converting the encoded JSON to an UTF8 encoded string and storing/retrieving this one:

```
func savePrices() {
   // this works too
   let json = try! JSONEncoder().encode(myPrices)
   UserDefaults.standard.set(String(data: json, encoding: .utf8), forKey: "prices")
}

func loadPrices() {
   // and this doesn't work either
   let json = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "prices")!.data(using: .utf8)

}
```

So, from the error raised, CodingKeys seems to be the root of the problem. I tried to switch over using NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver` with no success.

I'm really wondering if there is a simple/universal solution to save/load a Dictionary in UserDefaults?

All your comments and suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the below code in my project that will work for me.

> User Model

```
public protocol UserModel: Codable, PrimaryKey {

    var id: String { get }
    var firstName: String? { get }
    var lastName: String? { get }
    var userName: String? { get }
    var emails: [String] { get }
}

public struct User: UserModel {

    public let id: String
    public let firstName: String?
    public let lastName: String?
    public let userName: String?
    public let emails: [String]

    public enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "Id"
        case firstName = "FirstName"
        case lastName = "LastName"
        case userName = "UserName"
        case emails = "Emails"
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        do {
            self.id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
            self.firstName = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
            self.lastName = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .lastName)
            self.userName = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .userName)
            self.emails = try container.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .emails) ?? []
        }
        catch let error {
            debugPrint(error)
            throw error
        }
    }
}
```

I have stored in userDefault using below way

> User Data Class

```
class UserData: NSObject
{

let userDefaultKey = "user_information"

var userData: User?

    func getDictionary() -> [String: Data]
    {
        var dicInfo = [String: Data]()

        do
        {
            let _userData = try JSONEncoder().encode(userData)

            dicInfo["userData_default"]  = _userData

        }catch let error{
            print("error while save data in User Default: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        return dicInfo
    }
    func saveToDefault()
    {
        let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
        userDefault.set(getDictionary(), forKey: userDefaultKey)
        userDefault.synchronize()
    }
    func loadFromDefault()
    {
        let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
        if let dicInfo = userDefault.object(forKey: userDefaultKey) as? [String: Data]
        {
            update(dicInfo)
        }
    }
    func update(_ dictionaryInfo: [String: Data])
    {
        do
        {
            if let _userData_data = dictionaryInfo["userData_default"]
            {
                if let _userData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: _userData_data) {
                    userData = _userData
                }
            }

            saveToDefault()

        }catch let error{
            print("error while load From Default data in User Default: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: While I appreciate your answer, it doesn't help that much. Your data structure seems different. Why are you introducing a protocol structure? Thx.

Comment: @hopfi2k Actually, I have one another struct where I have declared all variables as a `var` to store the user input value and manage the API call structure.